# JSON : how to save JSON Array using Java and loop till last JSON Object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm new to JSON and have below file. I have to save the array "steps" in java and need to loop the objects "duration" , "status"  and "Keyword".

```
"steps": [
      {
        "result": {
          "duration": 7128811788,
          "status": "passed"
        },
        "line": 5,
        "name": "The Browser is Launched and Smart Business URL is loaded",
        "match": {
          "location": "Common_Login.the_Browser_is_Launched_and_Smart_Business_URL_is_loaded()"
        },
        "keyword": "Given "
      },]
```

I tried below but didn't worked.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./target/JSON/Output.json"));
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;
System.out.println(jsonArray);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObjectRow = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
    name = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("duration");
    id = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("status");
    uri = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("name");
    status = (String) jsonObjectRow.get("location");
}
```

Comment: "didn't worked' in what way? Also please format your code.

Comment: No It didn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the best way to load a JSONObject from a json text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463414/what-s-the-best-way-to-load-a-jsonobject-from-a-json-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463414/what-s-the-best-way-to-load-a-jsonobject-from-a-json-text-file).

There are so many libraries build in for doing this task. But look at the question above.

Comment: If you think the question you link to is similar to this one and has already been answered, you should flag it as a duplicate and not use it as an answer.

Comment: I don't have the privileges to flag it duplicate. Thats why there is a reference to the original answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the built-in class from Java you can have a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17399110/3977134

You are missing the part from the `parseJson` function in the referenced answer.

For simplicity I'd suggest to you to use [`org.json`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) which is just one of many good libraries to use for JSON parsing in Java. If you are interested see here:

[Parse JSON with org.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442347/parse-json-with-org-json)

[Parsing JSON in Java Using org.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455305/parsing-json-in-java-using-org-json)